# Posso ter mais de uma FK referenciando a uma mesma PK?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu referenciar chaves estrangeiras(FK) de tabelas diferentes a uma mesma chave primaria(PK). Abaixo está um pedaço do comando SQL

```
CREATE TABLE Run(
Project_Code INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Projects(Project_Code),
)

CREATE TABLE Sen(
Project_Code INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Projects(Project_Code),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível, sim. Perfeitamente normal e amplamente utilizado.